# Unable to Create group in library permissions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a library in sharepoint which is not inheriting permissions from its parent site. However, when I go to library permissions, then to the Edit Tab->Grant group, there is no option to 'Create a Group'. There is an option to Grant Permissions to Individual users. Can somebody explain why there is no option to Create  a Group in library permissions. I read the sharepoint manual and there should be such an option

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Groups can be created only on SPWeb level.
In your case you can created the group in the web containing this list, add required users and then you can grant permissions for this group to the list.